# Functions in Access SQL not available in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I posted a question a few days ago. I have a query made with the query wizard in Access (I am by no means an SQL expert) and was trying to connect Excel directly to my data source (Oracle ORAD database) and it wasn't working. We determined that is because the SQL generated from Access is not the type of SQL the Oracle DB will interpret.

My Access based SQL query uses functions:

- Trim
- IIf(IsNull([Table1]),[Table 2], [Table 3])
- Val([Table 4])
- Sum
- (in the format): Sum(IIf(Not(IsNull([Table])),[Table], 0))

Which functions can I keep and which should I change, and what should I change them to? I keep trying to look things up in the Oracle Help website but it is confusing and there aren't many examples of syntax.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it's better to explain what you want to achieve, Oracle has its own functions and they can be way different from SQL Server ones. Table's definition and your generated query will also help a lot

Comment: I would search Google instead. `oracle sql trim`, `oracle sql iif`, `oracle sql val` - they all have the information you are looking for on the first page of results.